# Name generated for foreign key overwrites existing column name

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Code First EF v6.0. I have a table MyTable, which should have 3 columns:
Id (the private key), Name and OtherTable_Name (the foreign key).

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Index(IsUnique = true)]
[MaxLength(400)]
public string Name { get; private set; } 

public virtual OtherTable ARandomStringName { get; set; }
```

I was getting a weird bug where Name was populated with the value of OtherTable_Name, and no foreign key was generated.
I renamed the private key of OtherTable to OtherTableName. Now I get a database table which has Id, Name, and OtherTable_OtherTableName.

This solves my immediate problem - missing foreign key, incorrect Name value - but I don't understand why it was happening in the first place. (And I'd rather be able to refer to the field sensibly as OtherTable.Name, not OtherTable.OtherTableName.)

When does EF prefix foreign key column names with OtherTable_, and when does it not? This bug has not happened on any pair of tables where both have "Id" as the private key column - is it anything to do with the field being the private key in one table and not the other? What should I be doing to avoid this kind of bug happening elsewhere?

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you put in the actual code you used rather than describing it. e.g. how you actually coded this: "OtherTable_Name (string, foreign key)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataAnnotations` to override EF conventions. Make sure you have a reference to

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

then simply add the `ForeignKey` attribute to your `NavigationProperty`

```
public int OtherTableId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("OtherTableId")]
public virtual OtherTable OtherTableItem { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes, but when do I need to do this? I don't want to do it for every foreign key in my entire database, 'just in case', when the vast majority of my code does the right thing already.

Comment: When you don't want EF conventions naming your ForeignKeys TableName_ColumnName and you wish to control it yourself as you said in the question. If some of the relationships work as you wish then don't change them ;)

Comment: Could you point me at some documentation for the conventions? Unless the only way to tell whether EF will prepend column names with the foreign key table name is to try it and see if it breaks!
I've searched, but only found how to override the conventions, not what they actually are.

Comment: @Ollyver I'm not sure how much of this book is available online but its worth a look https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s02.html